# Blender Internal: How do I add motion blur?

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

just wondering where to enable motion blur in the blender internal render engine.

It's supposed to be in the render settings called "sampled motion blur" but I can't find it.
I am using Blender 2.74

[Download demo-file here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B89oIuOBdiu0RzBTSTc2Z1dXRzA/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: It should be [right there](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KsEiB.png).. Have you tried reloading factory settings?

Comment: @gandalf3 not yet, how do I do that?

Comment: *Info* (near the top of the window by default) *> File > Load Factory Settings*

Comment: @gandalf3 okay, I found out when I make a new file or reload the factory settings Sampled motion blur returns to my render settings.

Somehow this problem is connected with the file I am working with. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: That's strange.. Is it possible you could upload the file in question?

Comment: @gandalf3 actually not :/ its an unreleased customer project I can't share... I know its hard to figure it out without file, but my hands are tied.

Comment: What if you delete all the objects etc? If the problem persists, could you upload it then?

Comment: @gandalf3 good idea. I killed all objects. problem still present. I attached the file in my question.

Comment: Hm.. That really is strange. If I had to guess, perhaps a bug in an addon or something caused it to disappear at one point, and then that was saved in the file. To fix it, you could append everything into a new file. A bit of a clumsy solution, but perhaps easier than setting the motion blur settings through the python console.

Comment: @gandalf3 yep, you just described my worst case scenario since the scene has a lot of linked proxies in it and I can't easily append everything from the corrupted file. Seems like I have to deal with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sampled motion blur is not available in Blender internal when the Full Sample option is enabled in Anti-Aliasing.

The solution is to turn off Full Sample.

[image]